# Solve $BAB^{-1}=J$ for matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have 3 Matrices : $A , B$ and $J.$ I know matrices $A$ and $J. J$ is the real jordan normal form of $A.$ The relationship between the three matrices is given by $BAB^{-1} =J.$

How can I find the matrix $B.$

For example,

$A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 \\
     1 &-1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$J= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    1  & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$BAB^{-1}=J$ can be written as $BA-JB=0$. That's as far as I got.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) in your example J, doesn't appear to be Jordan normal.  2)Have you learned about eigenvectors?  How about generalized eigenvectors?

Comment: Doug, Thanks for your reply.
The Jordan Normal would be [ -i 0 0 ; 0 i 0; 0 0 1] and the eigen values are +/- i and 1 for the A matrix. the problem I am trying to solve (big picture) wants me to convert the Jordan Normal form to a real Jordan Normal form and thats how I arrived at the J matrix.

Could you say a little more on how eigenvectors would help ? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$BA - JB = 0$ can be considered as a $9 \times 9$ system of linear equations in the entries of $B$.  Solve that system.

Answer (score 1):

The columns of the transform matrix $B$ are the real and imaginary parts of the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\pm i$ (that's the first two columns!) then the eigenvector corresponding to the final eigenvalue of 1.

Calculate these to show that $B=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 0 && 1 \\
0 && -1 && 1 \\
-1 && 0 && 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Answer (score 0):

$\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$

$-(\lambda-1)(\lambda+i)(\lambda-i)$

Complex eigenvalues 
Here is a little trick

$(B^{-1} A B)^2 = J^2\\
B^{-1} A^2 B = J^2$

And $A^2$ has real eigenvalues and the same matrices $B, B^{-1}$

$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\1&-1&1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

and $J^2 = \begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

And we know that $-1,-1,1$ will be the eigenvalues of $A^2.$  Find the associated vectors.

$A^2 \begin{bmatrix}-1&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix} J^2$

$B  = \begin{bmatrix}-1&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$
And I will leave it to you to find $B^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks a lot Doug,

I found this example in a thesis written in french and was trying to interpret the steps involved . The B matrix the author has calculated is B

B= [ 1 -1 0 ;
      0  -1 1 ;
      1  0  1]

and that confused me. I will go through the steps you have outlined with another example and make sure I understand the steps involved. Thanks again :)

P.S. I apologize for the lack of formatting in my posts. I am new here and will learn that soon.

Comment: there is not a unique matrix $B.$  Regading the formatting.  You can right-click on most objects and see the source for it.  And this will help. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference